# How to store data with variables size(1-30 mb) in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, crud, gridfs, atomic

I am using Mongo-java Driver 2.13. I want to store pdf files of varying size(1mb to 30mb).

> Note: I know I can't store a document having size greater than 16mb in
>   MongoDB. Then, I need to use GridFS.

I want to save pdf files of small size(<16 mb) in `BookPDFs` collection in normal way. For larger files, I need to store it using GridFS(in `fs.chunks` and `fs.files`). When I want to retrieve all PDFs, it need to access `BookPDFs` collection and `fs.chunks`, `fs.files` collections. It will loose **atomicity** for that find operation and also, it will take much time to get data from different collections.

While fetching data, I don't need it in chunks. So GridFS is not of so much use here. What should be the best way:

- Save all of my data in GridFS.(title, author, etc fields in `fs.files` as
  metadata)
- Save data in different collections according to size
- Any other approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to save smaller files directly? Save all to gridfs

Comment: @SergioTulentsev  It will take more time to fetch data using GridFS for smaller files. Also update operation is not atomic in GridFS.

Comment: @dev: do you have detailed info that GridFS updates aren't atomic? The updates to the `fs.files` collection are for sure. You could store the additional data there. That would save you a whole query (or an regular aggregation).

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Atomicity of GridFS update is not guaranteed. Please check : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#when-should-i-use-gridfs

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg  I simplified the question.

Comment: @dev: that is about the content of the file, not the metadata. So I assume you have a use case where the whole content needs to be updated? This can be achieved by setting a "locked" flag of the metadata while the update is performed and check wether the file is locked before an update operation. While this sounds complex, it is worth the work, since you only have to do this in case you perform the (presumably) relatively rare update instead of doing multiple queries each time you need to find a file.